# setting QComboBox text with multiple columns

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox that contains QTableView like below. When I select a row, QComboBox title shows only "Alex" but i want "Alex - Alex address". How can i do it?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried signal [QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) in combination with [QComboBox::setEditText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setEditText)? I'm not quite sure whether this works as well if [editable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#editable-prop) is `false` but might be worth to check out.

Comment: Hi. It worked. Please answer the question and I'll accept. @Scheff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435166/setting-qcombobox-text-with-multiple-columns#comment117450191_66435166):

> Have you tried signal QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index) in combination with QComboBox::setEditText()? I'm not quite sure whether this works as well if editable is false but might be worth to check out.

and OP asked for an answer as this seemed to be valuable.

So, here we go:

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// table data entry
struct Entry {
  int i;
  std::string name;
  std::string address;
};

// custom table model
class TableModel: public QAbstractTableModel {
  private:
    std::vector<Entry> _entries;

  public:
    explicit TableModel(QObject *pQParent = nullptr):
      QAbstractTableModel(pQParent)
    { }

    template <typename ITER>
    TableModel(ITER first, ITER last, QObject *pQParent = nullptr) :
      TableModel(pQParent)
    {
      for (; first != last; ++first) _entries.push_back(*first);
    }

    virtual ~TableModel() = default;

    TableModel(const TableModel&) = delete;
    TableModel& operator=(const TableModel&) = delete;

    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
      return (int)_entries.size();
    }

    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
      return 3;
    }

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
      const size_t i = (size_t)index.row();
      if (i >= _entries.size()) return QVariant();
      if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        switch (index.column()) {
          case 0: return _entries[i].i;
          case 1: return QString::fromStdString(_entries[i].name);
          case 2: return QString::fromStdString(_entries[i].address);
        }
      }
      return QVariant();
    }
};

// sample data
const Entry entries[] = {
  { 1, "Alex", "Alex address" },
  { 5, "Ben", "Ben address" },
  { 6, "Mary", "Mary address" },
  { 2, "Max", "Max address" },
  { 4, "Nicole", "Nicole address" },
  { 3, "Tim", "Tim address" }
};

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  TableModel qTblModel(std::begin(entries), std::end(entries));
  QComboBox qCBox;
  qCBox.setWindowTitle("Test QComboBox with Table Model");
  QTableView qTblView(&qCBox);
  qTblView.setModel(&qTblModel);
  qTblView.horizontalHeader()->hide();
  qTblView.verticalHeader()->hide();
  qTblView.resizeColumnsToContents();
  qTblView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView::SelectRows);
  qCBox.setView(&qTblView);
  qCBox.setModel(&qTblModel);
  qCBox.setEditable(true); // allow access to line edit
  qCBox.lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true); // prevent editing in line edit
  qCBox.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qCBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
    [&](int i) {
      if ((size_t)i < std::size(entries)) {
        qCBox.setEditText(
          QString::fromStdString(entries[i].name + " | " + entries[i].address));
      }
    });
  qCBox.setCurrentIndex(-1);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQComboBoxTableModel.exe (animated)]

It's in fact necessary to set `QComboBox::editable` to `true` to make `QComboBox::setEditText()` working.

To prevent accidental user-editing, I set in turn the embedded `QLineEdit` to `readOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a table, you can set the att "Selection behaviour" to `select Rows`

[image]

Comment: I have already done that but it still shows only first column of my QTableView.

Comment: @Ms.Sahin Then please provide the code -- preferably a [mcve] -- that can be used to reproduce the problem.  Otherwise all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: My purpose to ask this question is to learn if it is possible so there is no written code for the question. @G.M.